# Computer won't pass POST

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi

When my computer powers on it just shows a black screen on the monitor, can't press f11 to go into UEFI and it just hangs there until I pull the plug or hold power. This happens every other power cycle. When it boots fine it boots perfectly fine. When it doesn't boot the phase lights on it are in phase 1

Motherboard is a MSI 970a-46g

Already checked RAM and reseated it.

HDD is pretty old... From my old Vista computer. Could it be that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard drive related. Since you can't boot in BIOS, the computer fail on the self-post phrase. During the self-post phrase, computer test the device like the keyboard and other peripheral devices, and other hardware elements like the processor, storage devices, and memory.

By default, if you have the problem when power on self-test, there will a error pop up on the screen.However, if the problem lies with the video card, and therefore you can't see anything on the monitor,then looking for an error message wouldn't be as helpful as listening for a beep code or reading a POST code with a POST test card.

Comment: Thank you. I  believe it most likely is the motherboard. I get usb support, so if it pasts POST my keyboard lights up. I get none of that. Resset CMOS, tried different gpus and still the same thing.